# PHP - keeping the 0 non-significant in the sum

Tags: php, sum

In the database I have a field with values such as `C50003`.

I have a function that divides this value into: `C5` and `0003`.

Now I need to **add 1 to 0003**, which would become 0004.

The problem is that when I do the sum (0003 + 1) the **result is 4 and not 0004**. (I have already tried doing 0003 + 0001, but nothing changes).

To fix this error I would have to count the number of initial 0's and put them back to the final result, but that would be a laborious check.

**Is there any way to keep those 0's?**

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: rather than store just `C50003`, store in one column `C5`, then in another as an int `3`, then you can increment the value with ease, then you can pad it when you want to display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As easy way:

```php
$value = '0003';
$intValue = (int) $value;
$newValue = $intValue + 1;
$formattedValue = str_pad($newValue, strlen($value), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $formattedValue; // 0004

$value = '0012'; // => 0013
```

UPD: Change `strlen($value) - strlen($intValue) + 1` to `strlen($value)` on the advice of @user1597430.

Comment: `strlen($value) - strlen($intValue) + 1` must be replaced with `strlen($value)`

Comment: @user1597430, I agree, it will look cleaner.